# nodejs array not being copied?

Tags: arrays, node.js, serial-port

Im making a state machine using NodeJS, using the serial port i need to receive and send a series of commands to verify that the communication was correct, on my second state i receive 31 bytes of data and need to resend them on my fourth state, for that i simply copy the received array to send it later but on my fourth state console.log shows nothing, what can be happening?

Here is my code:

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport');
const ByteLength = SerialPort.parsers.ByteLength;
const port = new SerialPort("COM6");
const parser = new ByteLength({length: 1});
port.pipe(parser);

var state = 0;
var cache = [];
var history;

parser.on('data', function (data) {
    cache.push(data[0]);
    flowcontrol();
});

function porterr() {
    console.log('error');
    process.exit(1);
}

function flowcontrol() {

    switch (state) {
        case 0:
            // ---------------------------------------------
            //  State 0 -> Recives ENQ, Sends ACK
            // ---------------------------------------------
            // Receives 1 byte
            if (cache.length !== 1) {
                return;
            }

            // Verify answer received
            if (cache[0] !== 5) {
                // Wrong answer received
                porterr();
            }

            console.log('state ' + state);
            // Sends Answer, clears cache, and waits for next state
            port.write(Buffer.from([6]));
            state++;
            cache.length = 0;
            break;

        case 1:
            // ---------------------------------------------
            //  State 1 -> Recives DATA, Sends ACK
            // ---------------------------------------------
            // Receives 31 bytes
            if (cache.length !== 31) {
                return;
            }

            console.log('state ' + state);
            history = cache; // <--- data is saved for later use

            // Sends Answer, clears cache, and waits for next state
            port.write(Buffer.from([6]));
            state++;
            cache.length = 0;
            break;

        case 2:
            // ---------------------------------------------
            //  State 1 -> Recives EOT, Sends ENQ
            // ---------------------------------------------
            // Receives 1 byte
            if (cache.length !== 1) {
                return;
            }

            // Verify answer received
            if (cache[0] !== 4) {
                // Wrong answer received
                porterr();
            }

            console.log('state ' + state);
            // Sends Answer, clears cache, and waits for next state
            port.write(Buffer.from([5]));
            state++;
            cache.length = 0;
            break;

        case 3:
            // ---------------------------------------------
            //  State 3 -> Recives ACK, Sends DATA
            // ---------------------------------------------
            // Receives 1 byte
            if (cache.length !== 1) {
                return;
            }

            // Verify answer received
            if (cache[0] !== 6) {
                // Wrong answer received
                porterr();
            }

            console.log('state ' + state);
            console.log[history]; // <-- Nothing is shown here!!!

            // Sends Answer, clears cache, and waits for next state
            //port.write(Buffer.from(history));
            //state++;
            //cache.length = 0;
            break;

        default:
            console.log('not yet completed');
            console.log(cache.length);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean console.log(history)?

Comment: Yes.. history is not being shown

Comment: Because you wrote console.log[history] instead?

Comment: Assignment of objects or arrays in Javascript does not make a separate copy of the data.  It just copies a pointer to the same object/array.  So, then you have two variables pointing at the same object.  Change one and they both see the change because they both point at the same object.  If you want to save a copy of the data, you have to explicitly make a copy of it.

Comment: @uNiverseIEgacy duh!... you're completely right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not assign an object with equal to sign in javascript.

use Object.assign or lodash for that.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#cloneDeep

What is happening in your code is when you change the value of cache.length = 0; it also changes the value of history.
since it's an object not a reference type.